# Can't sign out of App Store

Tags: mac-appstore

I am unable to sign out of App Store. I click Sign Out in the Store menu but it doesn't take; I am still signed in.  I'm running Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: What problem or issue are you trying to address by signing out?